# R: Sample data from model, package `ks`

Tags: r

I'm sorry if this has an obvious answer someplace, I haven't been able to find one and I'm not too experienced with R.

I'm using the kernel-smoothing package `ks` to produce a kernel-density estimation model using `kde`. I would like to then sample the model produced.

```
library(ks)
data <- read.table("data_file.txt", header=FALSE)
model <- kde(data)
```

And then I'm not sure how to proceed. I had read the help document but hadn't found the necessary function.

Answer (score 2):

**Univariate case**

Please refer to the help document:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ks/ks.pdf

You can see `dkde`,`pkde`,`qkde`,`rkde` as same as any R distribution.

```
rkde(100, model)
```

It'll generate 100 random number from estimated distribution.

**Multivariate case**

I'm surprised finding ks package whick don't prodive sample method directly. Anyway it's easily in principle. You only need first to select randomly a sample point and then to apply a estimated kernel noise on it. For slow but basic code example with multivariate normal kernel:

```
library(mvtnorm)

rmkde <- function(size,flat){
  n <- nrow(flat$x)
  s <- sample(1:n,size,replace=TRUE)
  t(apply(flat$x[s,],1,function(mean)rmvnorm(1,mean=mean,sigma=flat$H)))
}

rmkde(100, model)
```

Since `rmvnorm` compute same matrix decomposition many times, it is slow, you can pick decomposition from `rmvnorm` source code to accelerate it.